# Java testing for a race condition

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

Say in thread one, I am modifying a resource, key-value map. And in thread two, it is also modifying the same key in the resource.

Then I wrote to the code to detect this case and do the right thing.

To confirm that it is doing the right thing as expected, I want to write a test case.

How would one go about simulating this exact race condition? There is a limitation on mocking because key is an object of a final class

Is there way to set breakpoints to control what gets executed in what order?

Comment: You can use sleep statements to simulate thread scheduling. Or keep running concurrent code until you get a collision.

Comment: Looking for a reproducible test case to run as a part of integration testing so I wouldn't be able to just concurrent forever hoping to hit it as it does not happen often in prod. How would you inject such a sleep statements if those race conditions are wrapped in some function. Any examples ?

Comment: There's no code for us to work with.

Comment: For example, if I just mimic the same code in a test and inject a sleep statement  then it could deviate if I make changes to the real code down the road

Comment: Can you post some code, of the threads which are trying to modify the map? Also, I don't think it is any consequence if the class of the Key is final. But a sample code would shed some light on that too.

Comment: I've played with CountDownLatch and that seems to give me the control i am looking for

Comment: Depends what you're testing for. It may conceal visibility bugs.